# Need Help Using Proof by Contraposition

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> Let $x$ be a real number. Prove that if $x^3+5x+1\le0$, then $x<0.$

My solution: Suppose that $x\ge0$, what should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $x\ge 0,$ then $x^3+5x+1\ge 1>0$. So, by contraposition we have shown the statement. More generally, the idea is that a statement $p\implies q$ is equivalent to the statement $\neg q\implies \neg p$.

Here, we assume $\neg q$. That is, that $x$ is not less than $0$. That's the same thing as saying that $x$ is greater than or equal to $0$. $x\ge 0$.

Using this, we'd like to show the negation of $x^3+5x+1\le 0$, $\neg p$. That is, we'd like to show that assuming that $x\ge 0$, $x^3+5x+1>0$.

Comment: Why does has to be x^3 + 5x + 1 >= 1 ?

Comment: If $x\ge 0$, $x^3\ge 0$, and $5x\ge 0$. So, $x^3+5x+1\ge 1>0$.

Comment: Why does x^3 + 5x + 1>= 1 has to be exactly >=1. Why can't we just say that x^3 + 5x + 1 >= 0. only

Comment: Note that we need to prove that $x^3+5x+1>0$. So, by showing that $x^3+5x+1\ge 1$, we have shown (in particular) that it is $>0$.

Comment: uhaa I got it partially

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What does $x\geq 0$ imply about your expression $x^3+5x+1$?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on contrapositive, then $\neg q \implies \neg p$ then slowly building up the argument yields
$$x \geq 0 \implies x + 1 \geq 0, \ x^3 \geq 0, \text{and} \ 5x \geq 0\\
\implies x^3 + 5x \geq 0 \implies x^3 + 5x + 1 > 0$$
Which is precisely $\neg p$

Answer (score 0):

For all $a,b,c,d$ we have $$a\geq 0\land b\geq 0\implies ab\geq 0\land a+b\geq 0.$$ $$c\geq 0\implies c+d\geq d.$$ With $a=b=x$ we have $x\geq 0\implies x^2\geq 0.$

Hence with $a=x^2$ and $b=x$ we have $x\geq 0\implies (x^2\geq 0\land x\geq 0)\implies x^3\geq 0.$

With $a=5$ and $b=x$ we have $x\geq 0\implies 5x\geq 0.$

Hence with $a=x^3$ and $b=5x$ and  $c=x^3+5x$ and $d=1$ we have $$x\geq 0\implies (x^3\geq 0\land 5x\geq 0)\implies$$ $$\implies x^3+5x\geq 0\implies (x^3+5x)+1\geq 0+1=1>0.$$ Therefore $x\geq 0\implies x^3+5x+1>0.$ Equivalently $x^3+5x+1\not >0\implies x\not \geq 0.$